# Android Studio, Error: package does not exist

Tags: java, android

I was suffering form this over couple weeks, and it is killing me.

I am working on an android project in Android studio. I imported Haibison lockpattern as module to this projects.

in "settings.gradle" i add

```
include ':androidlockpattern'
```

in "build.gradle" i add

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':androidlockpattern')
    ...
}
```

When I run the project, which print errors
    "Error: package Haibison.android.lockpattern.util" does not exist.

I checked thousands times, the package is just right there, and when I import the package in my code:

```
import haibison.android.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity;
import haibison.android.lockpattern.util.AlpSettings
```

It just looks fine...
Plz help.

Comment: `Haibison.android.lockpattern.util` != `haibison.android.lockpattern.util`

Comment: Thanks, but that's my typo, error and package are actually all low case

Answer (score -2):

Try using this in your gradle project:
`compile 'haibison.android:underdogs:+`

Hope this helps!